# MongoDB add createAt updatedAt field java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I am interested in knowing how to have the createdAt and updatedAt field on mongo when using java sync driver.

I know how to do it in mongoose

```
const SchemaName = new Schema({
//myschema
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

I wanted to know how can I achieved the same in java, I know one possibility of having the createdAt and updatedAt field in schema and updating the value during insertion and updation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [javax.persistence](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/persistence/package-summary.html) annotations, with @PrePersist and @PreUpdate.

> @PrePersist

It will be called before persist the data in the database, with `updatable = false` it will be recorded just once.

> @PreUpdate

It will be called before insert the data in the database, and it is called every insert.

Your entity need to inherit the AbstractEntity class below:

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    public class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8087154111957605234L;

        @Column(name = "CREATED_AT", updatable=false)
        private Date createdAt;

        @Column(name = "UPDATED_AT")
        private Date updatedAt;

        public Date getCreatedAt() {
            return createdAt;
        }

        public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
            this.createdAt = createdAt;
        }

        @PrePersist
        protected void onCreate() {
            createdAt = new Date();
        }

        @PreUpdate
        protected void onUpdate() {
            updatedAt = new Date();
        }
     }
```